# AG Grid - isCancelAfterEnd state in cellEditingStopped?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have an angular app and I am using AG Grid.
While editing the value of a cell I call "isCancelAfterEnd()" when the input is not valid.
Now my question is:
Is it possible to get this info ("input was cancelled") when accessing the params in "(cellEditingStopped)"?

Does anyone understand what I mean? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but you can do something like the following

```
 isCancelAfterEnd(): boolean {
        this.params.node.isCancelled  = true;
        return true;
    };
```

and

```
  cellEditingStopped(event)
  {
    console.log(event.node.isCancelled);
    delete event.node.isCancelled;
  }
```